# Mailgun API: "'from' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation"

Tags: python, curl

Trying to run a very simple python program for test. Following is the code:

```
import requests
def send_email():
files = [
('to', '<my-email-address>'),
('subject', 'Thank you from Foo'),
('text', 'Hello World'),
('from', '\"Info\" <info@foo.com>'),
]
r =requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mail1.parkl.com/messages', files=files, auth=('api', '<my-key>'))
print r.text, r.status_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
send_email()
```

It spits out {
  "message": "'from' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation"
} 400

I have tried various option for From parameter but none seem to work.
"Info" , info@foo.com, info@mail1.foo.com

Reading online it seems I am not the first one running into this issue but could someone point me how to fix this and move ahead.

A curl request with exact same parameter just works fine:

```
curl -s —user 'api:<my-key>' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mail1.parkl.com/messages \
-F from=‘Foo <info@foo.com>' \
-F to=<my-email-address> \
-F subject='Info Hello' \
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape characters would not be required in the value for From parameter when specifying a display name. Though, you could use double quote for the display name like so:

```
import requests

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-<api-key-here>"),
        data={"from": '"Excited User" <foo@bar.com>',
              "to": "example@foo.com",
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun Awesomeness!"})

print send_simple_message().text
```

Or set the value for the From parameter in single or double quotes such as:

```
"from": 'Excited User <foo@bar.com>'
```

** *Disclaimer I work at Mailgun* **