# message: 'from parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation'

Tags: node.js, mailgun

Hi all I am facing this problem with mailgun, mail sends OK in localhost, but it does'nt send when I move to server online. My server is hosted via AWS and the error it shows is  `message: 'from parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation'`
My code is below

```
const mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
const DOMAIN = 'mailing.medappafrica.com';
const mg = mailgun({ apiKey: process.env.api_key, domain: DOMAIN });

module.exports.sendConfirmationEmail = (name, email, confirmationCode) => {
    const data = {
        from: `Medapp Verify <noreply@${DOMAIN}>`,
        to: email,
        subject: 'Please confirm your account',
        html: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif]-->
...code too long
```

Comment: Can you specify the version you're using of mailgun-js ? Both on your server and your machine ?

Comment: ``` "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0"```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mailgun API: "'from' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853171/mailgun-api-from-parameter-is-not-a-valid-address-please-check-documentatio)

Comment: @jnv Wasn't able to. But I had to use this package to parse my email https://www.npmjs.com/package/address-rfc2822